# SSH keys missing

Tags: ssh, fedora

I am SSHing into my Amazon EC2 instance on a daily basis. In order to do so I have to provide the private key. I have used `ssh-add <private key>`, and then it works!

However. Once in a while I have to repeat the `ssh-add` step because it seems like the key has gone missing on the same computer. This is very annoying, and it seems to happen at random.

Is this a known issue? How do I solve it?

I am using Fedora 17, Zsh and SSH version OpenSSH_5.9p1.

Comment: What happens around the time a key disappears (ie. system update, code deployment, application crash, &tc)? When you say a key is missing, is it not being displayed with `ssh-add -l`? Could be a permission issue on the parent directory.

Comment: @emcconville It happens upon rebooting. But perhaps that's how it is supposed to work? Is there any way I can add the key permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check .zshenv

Some flavors of Zsh issue `ssh-agent -k` command, followed by `ssh-add` in `~/.zshenv`. This will clear out any previous stored ssh keys, and load your user's default keys. You might just need to add the following line to `~/.zshenv`

```
tty -s && ssh-add
```

### Permanently add key for a user

`ssh-add` will scan for keys in your `~/.ssh` directory. Ensure that the dierctory has 700 permissions. The `ssh-add` command will check & load the following keys

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa
~/.ssh/id_dsa
~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
~/.ssh/identity
```

If you want to add your customer EC2 key at login, you can append `ssh-add <yourkey>` command to `~/.zshenv` (like above), or add a record to `~/.ssh/config`. Some good examples [here](http://lugatgt.org/2009/10/28/ssh-tips-and-tricks-2/).

```
Host your.ec2.domain.amazon.com
 IdenitityFile ~/path/to/your/custome/key
```

Comment: Just adding the entry to `~/.ssh/config` worked flawlessly!